# @MockBean service field is always null in a Test class with @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to improve a unit test for a service I'm developing. I read somewhere that it's ideal to use `@WebMvcTest` annotation over `@SpringBootTest` when testing the Web or Controller layer.

However, for some reason, a `@MockBean` **service** field I am using in the Test class is always `NULL`.

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expecting actual not to be null

In the test class below, `serviceIsLoaded()` method is always null when I run that single test.

**SectionRESTControllerTest.java**

```
@WebMvcTest
public class SectionRESTControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private SectionServiceImpl sectionServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void serviceIsLoaded() {
        assertThat(sectionServiceImpl).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

**SectionServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class SectionServiceImpl implements SectionService {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SectionServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private SectionRepository sectionRepo; //saves to section table
    @Autowired
    private GradeLevelRepository gradeLevelRepo;

    @Override
    public Section createSection(Section section) {...}

    @Override
    public Section updateSection(Section request) throws Exception {...}

    @Override
    public Section getSectionById(Long id) {
        return sectionRepo.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Section> getAllActiveSections() {
        return sectionRepo.findSectionByIsActiveTrue();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Section> getAllInActiveSections() {
        return sectionRepo.findSectionByIsActiveFalse();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Section> getSectionsByGradeLevelId(Long id) {
        return sectionRepo.findByGradeLevelId(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Section> getSectionByGradeLevelCode(String code) {
        return sectionRepo.findByGradeLevelCode(code);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Section> getSectionByGradeLevelCategory(String category) {
        return sectionRepo.findByGradeLevelCategory(category);
    }
}
```

My understanding is, with `@WebMvcTest`, it does not load the entire application context with all managed beans which makes the UnitTest run faster. Unlike, `@SpringBootTest` which loads everything when running the UnitTest.

**SectionService.java**

```
public interface SectionService {

    Section createSection(Section section);
    Section updateSection(Section section) throws Exception;
    Section getSectionById(Long id);
    List<Section> getAllActiveSections();
    List<Section> getAllInActiveSections();

    List<Section> getSectionsByGradeLevelId(Long id);
    List<Section> getSectionByGradeLevelCode(String code);
    List<Section> getSectionByGradeLevelCategory(String category);

}
```

**Main** class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AutoformSettingsServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AutoformSettingsServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Do you have any thoughts or ideas why the @MockBean sectionServiceImpl is null

Thank you.

Comment: What versions of JUnit and Spring (Boot) are you using?  According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) for `@WebMvcTest`, "When using JUnit 4, this annotation should be used in combination with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`" which would explain the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @rimesc You are exactly correct. You saved the day! I checked the version and saw I was using JUnit version 4. I added the required `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and it worked. Thank you.